# Informing java where to import from (lib)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, command-line, import, lwjgl

I'm using java from command line and coding in gedit, and am having trouble importing lwjgl.

I have my source code under src/uk/co/gossfunkel and have the lwjgl.jar in lib>jars and the natives under lib>natives. How do I let the compiler know that the `import org.lwjgl.*;` statement refers to org.lwjgl in lib>jars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
javac -cp /path/to/lib/jars/lwjgl.jar ...
```

for Unix.

```
javac -cp c:\path\to\lib\jars\lwjgl.jar ...
```

for Windows.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/classpath.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html for more explanations.

Comment: just curios, what is for Mac??

Comment: that seems to have killed about 6 errors, but the compiler still says "MainGame.java:4: package org.lwjgt does not exist"- what's this path relative to, my current directory, or overall?

Comment: mac is a Unix system, top one

Comment: Mac is like Unix. It uses forward slashes as directory separator, and : as path separator.

Comment: This path can be relative to the directory from which you execute the command, but in my example, it's an absolute path, since it starts with /.